# enableJetifier not working for library project

Tags: android, android-support-library, androidx, android-jetifier

My new kotlin project use androidx by default, with `android.useAndroidX=true` & `android.enableJetifier=true` configured in root project's `gradle.properties`. But it also depends on a module library which is using `support.v4` libraries.

Shouldn't Jetifier automatically transform those dependencies into androidx?
Why am I still get this error:

```
error: package android.support.v4.content does not exist
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;

error: cannot find symbol
   @DrawableRes int resId,
                                              ^
  symbol:   class DrawableRes
  location: class BitmapUtil

error: package android.support.annotation does not exist
import android.support.annotation.ColorRes;

error: cannot find symbol
    public static GDWrapper rect(@ColorRes int colorId, float... radii) {
                                  ^
  symbol:   class ColorRes
  location: class XmlDrawableUtil
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jetifier only applies to dependencies from maven (i.e., a line in your `dependencies` block of your `build.gradle` file); it does not apply to other modules in your project.

**Every** module in your project needs to move to AndroidX at the same time.